Holomorphic fibre bundles over noncompact Riemann surfaces
Some days ago I came across the paper "Holomorphic fiber bundles over Riemann surfaces", by H. Rohrl.
At the beginning of Section 1, the following theorem is quoted:

Theorem. Every fiber bundle over a noncompact Riemann surface is trivial, provided the structure group G is connected.

I knew the result to be true for holomorphic vector bundles on noncompact Riemann surfaces, but the fact that it holds for any holomorphic fibre bundle was unknown for me. However, the only references Rohrl gives are both in German, which I'm unable to follow:
[15] H. Grauert, Analytische Faserungen über holomorph-vollständigen Räumen, Math. Ann. 135 (1958), 263-273
[54] H. Rohrl, Das Riemann-Hilbertsche Problem der Theorie der linearen Differentialgleichungen, Math. Ann. 133 (1957), 1-25
Does anyone know a more up-to-date reference in English/French/Spanish for this result? Also, is it commonly accepted? I was a bit surprised that there was no reference to it in the literature.
Any help is very welcome!

I assume that this is meant to be a topological statement: every fiber bundle in the topological sense is trivial in the topological sense. A noncompact Riemann surface is homotopy-equivalent to a (generally infinite) graph, and a fiber bundle over a graph is trivial if the structure group is connected.

@TomGoodwillie Hmm as you can see in the link of the post, in the first paragraph of the paper he explicitly says that the triviality of fibre bundles is in a holomorphic sense.

@Tom Goodwillie: On a Stein manifold the topological and holomorphic classifications of $G$-bundles coincide, so this is indeed a purely topological problem.

@abx Oh, I didn't know that. So I guess that Tom's comment and yours solve my question. Thank you very much!

This is a theorem of Grauert, Satz I and II in §2 of your reference [15].

@TomGoodwillie Sorry, one last thing. Why are fibre bundles over graphs trivial? Is it easy to see? Do you know a reference if not?

@Don: graph is homotopy equivalent to a wedge of circle and any circle is nullhomotopic in the classifying space $BG$ which is simply-connected since $G$ is connected.

@IgorBelegradek Thank you!

@IgorBelegradek I was thinking again about this, and I see that since $BG$ is simply connected, every principal $G$-bundle is trivial. However, I don't understand your argument that this, combined with the fact that the base has the homotopy type of a wedge of circles, implies that every fibre bundle is trivial... Could you please elaborate on that?

@Don: I suppose it depends on what you mean by a "fiber bundle" which you never specified. The paper you linked talks about fiber bundles with structure group $G$, which is a Lie group (so connected=path-connected is equivalent to $BG$ simply-connected). You can read about fiber bundles e.g. in Husemoller's "Fibre bundles" where it is explained (chapter 4, theorem 6.2) that associating a fiber bundle to a principal bundle is functorial, and in particular, if a principal bundle is isomorphic to the trivial one, the same is true for the associated fiber bundle.

@IgorBelegradek Thank you for your answer. The notion of fibre bundle that I had in mind is the one given in Steenrod's book, as in the linked paper. I still have to convince myself that this and Husemoller's definition coincide (if they really coincide). Anyway, thank you for the reference.

If memory serves, they notions basically the same, maybe Steenrod specifies more structure, which comes for free but that requires some justification. What you actually need is 1) Every fiber bundle is associated to a principal bundle and 2) The association is such that isomorphic principal bundles corresponds to isomorphic fiber bundles.

@IgorBelegradek Hmm I think I got it now. Dear Igor, thank you for your help, I really appreciate it :)
